# Android Support Library v17

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, eclipse-luna

I just downloaded Eclipse 4.4 Luna and installed the latest ADT 20 on it. Now, new templates for new Android Project are included. One of them is "Android TV Activity".

The existing code uses Android Support Library v17!!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ImageCardView;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Presenter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

But I cannot find the new support library v17 anywhere! I've searched d.android.com, and still cannot find it. Where can I find it?

Comment: Have you tried looking this folder: <sdk>/extras/android/support?

Comment: @SteinDekker Yes. It's not there.

Comment: Yeah, I am missing that too, and I just updated to the latest Android Support package a few minutes ago. I'm not clear that they have released the Android TV pieces yet, though, so it may be that there's another update forthcoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Leanback library is available in the Support Repository. If you're using Gradle you can get it using:

```
compile "com.android.support:leanback-v17:+"
```

You can install the Support Repository package via the SDK manager, and you can see where Gradle pulls the dependency from at `<sdk root>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/leanback-v17/21.0.0-rc1`. However, I haven't used Eclipse for Android development for ages so I'm unaware if it even supports AAR libraries.

Comment: "I'm unaware if it even supports AAR libraries" -- it doesn't. And AFAIK we can't readily back-convert an AAR into a regular library project. Hopefully they will ship a regular library project as well at some point.

Comment: .aar files are some zip files. You can rename them, uncompress them and then move the sources in a new project. I know it's not a clear way... but it's still a way :)

Comment: FWIW, while Eclipse/ADT does not support AARs presently, [Maven for Android does](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AAR), and there is a recipe floating around for [converting AARs into ordinary Android library projects](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html). I have not yet tried that recipe with `leanback-v17`, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse ADT, you can get the leanback support libraries as APKLibs from the following project.

https://github.com/kingargyle/adt-leanback-support

It takes the source from the leanback libraries and dependencies and makes APKLibs and jars that Eclipse can then use.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation "com.android.support:leanback-v17:24.0.0"
```

Your version code `24.0.0` depends on your Android sdk, the latest version is `28.0.0`.

You can see all the versions in [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/leanback-v17).