# Android Support Library v17 for Eclipse

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop

I just started working on **Android-L**. I have created **HelloWorld** project in Eclipse. but i got red markers at every `android.support.v17` imports.

```
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ImageCardView;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Presenter;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter;
import android.support.v17.leanback.app.BackgroundManager;
import android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ArrayObjectAdapter;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HeaderItem;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ListRow;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ListRowPresenter;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.OnItemClickedListener;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Presenter;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Row;
```

I have already update my **Support Library** but i cant see any **Support V17** in my **SDK**.

So someone please point me how can i download it? I am using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Have you added the leanback library to your project?

Comment: @HiemanshuSharma ya mate i am sure....it's **v17**

Comment: See the comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439671/android-support-library-v17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the present time, `leanback-v17` is only available from Google as an AAR.

If you happen to be using Maven for your build system, the `android-maven-plugin` [supports AARs](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AAR).

Or, you can try to [convert the AAR into an Android library project](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html). I have not personally tried this approach with `leanback-v17` just yet, so I do not know if there are any specific problems that that AAR will cause.

Or, you can switch to Gradle for Android, with or without Android Studio, and consume the AAR "natively".

Comment: @CW I just read your comment at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439671/android-support-library-v17)

Comment: @SimplePlan: Thanks, I added another comment on the answer with a summarized version of what I have here.

Comment: @CW I got it. Now, i convert AAR into an `Android project library`...thnx for the idea.....

Answer (score 1):

I've built the Android TV leanback library as an set of APKLibs and JARs.  You can find those here.

https://github.com/kingargyle/adt-leanback-support

You'll need to run a mvn clean install, to build the libraries, and the jars.  You can then import the projects into your eclipse workspace and depend on them as you normally do.